# Why does Lefty say that he has to "check his lipstick"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, donnie-brasco

At about 39:13 in *Donnie Brasco*, when Al Pacino (lefty) said: "I'm checking my lipstick." What's that supposed to mean? When he looks backward with a mirror, is it because he is afraid to get whacked from the people behind?

Comment: Did this answer your question or should I clarify my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Lefty is in the car, he is indeed afraid of being "whacked". He's checking his mirror *to see the back seat of the car*, so he can keep an eye on everyone in the car and be ready for anything (in the hope he could do something about it).

We can see his fear from the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Donnie-Brasco.html):

> **SONNY** Hey, Left, what'cha doing?
>   **LEFTY** Just checking my part.
>   **SONNY** (chuckling) - Ah, Left--what am I gonna do
>                    without you? (to Donnie)       What
>                    would you do without this     guy,
>                    hah, kid? You'd have to       find
>                    yourself a new goombah.
>        Lefty getting VERY NERVOUS...
>                                **NICKY**
>                    That was something about the
>                    boss, wasn't it?
>                               **SONNY**
>                    We all gotta go sometime.
>        Lefty, TERRIFIED, looks at Boobie again. Boobie nods. Donnie
>        WATCHES this...
>   Thinks: what to do?
>        They walk from the parked Mercedes toward a FREIGHT HANGAR. The
>        scene is otherwise DESERTED. Lefty NERVOUS, lights a cigarette.
>        Planes periodically ROAR overhead.
>                                **NICKY**
>                           (sings)
>                     'Love on the rocks, ain't no
>                     surprise.'
>                                **LEFTY**
>                     Sonny, what is this? we glomming
>                     something?
>        Sonny opens the door.
>                                  **SONNY**
>                     After you.
>        Lefty walks into the DARKNESS...A terrifying SILENCE...Then--
>        RRRRRRROAR
>        The LIGHTS come up. A pale and shaken Lefty looks straight into the
>        eyes of a LION CUB as it GROWLS. A bluff FREIGHT HANDLER holds the
>        lion on a leash.
>                              **LEFTY**
>                    Christ. I think I shit my pants.
>                                  **FREIGHT HANDLER**
>                    It was supposed         to go to some
>                    animal dealer.    Fuck him. I'll
>                    tell him it got         lost.
>                               **SONNY**
>                    Look, Left, he likes you.
>        The cub nuzzles and sniffs at Lefty.
>                               **LEFTY**
>                          (to Lion)
>                    Get the fuck outta here.
>   **SONNY**
>                     That's for you, Left. For your
>                     birthday. Batter late than
>                     never.
>                               **LEFTY**
>                     That's why you sent for me?
>                             **SONNY**  Yeah, why? Whaddayou think, you
>                  was gonna get whacked?
>                   (laughing) Lefty thought he's gonna get whacked!

On an interesting side note, the scene you reference *isn't* in the theatrical version of the movie, but on the director's cut, [as can be seen here](http://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=4056).